# org.apache.http.legacy.jar Proguard error

Tags: android, android-proguard

When I use `httpclient-4.5.2.jar` + `httpcore-4.4.4.jar`, `Proguard` works fine. But when I replace the above to packages by `org.apache.http.legacy.jar`, following `Proguard` error is reported:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Note: there were 273 duplicate class definitions.
Warning: library class android.webkit.WebView depends on program class android.net.http.SslCertificate
Warning: library class android.webkit.WebView depends on program class android.net.http.SslCertificate
Warning: library class android.webkit.WebViewClient depends on program class android.net.http.SslError
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 3 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

use this below code into your `build.gradle` instead import jar file :

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

> For reference check this code :

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.application.abc"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```