# Can anyone tell me how to handle >compile: org.apache.http.legacy this error in linux?

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33914693/5183999

Answer (score 0):

use below code into your `build.gradle` file

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

> For reference check this code

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931410/org-apache-http-legacy-jar-proguard-error/38931603#38931603)